# How to change the color of the certain element when there are multiple element with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have HTML structure like:

```
<a class="parent-element">
 <h2 class="link1">link</h2>
</a>

<a class="parent-element">
 <h2 class="link2">link</h2>
</a>

<a class="parent-element">
 <h2 class="link3">link</a>
</a>
```

I want to add the class to the parent element for clicked link, and for instance, I click on the "link1" then change the background of his parent then when I click on the "link2" add the class to "link2" and remove from "link1"

I was trying with:

```
     $(".parent-element").addClass("myClass");
```

But, it's far from what I want to get :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Within your click handler, use `function() { ..` and then you can use `this` which refers to the element clicked, so `$(this).closest(".parent-element").addClass(...`

Comment: Can you give it an answer, please? I am not so familiar with JS :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` keyword for adding class to the current element.

```js
$(".parent-element").click(function() {
  $(".parent-element").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active{
   color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link1">link</h2>
</a>

<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link2">link</h2>
</a>

<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link3">link</h2>
</a>
```

Comment: It works :) But, not on the first click in my case?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Works on second click. Like I click on "link1" nothing happens, and then when I click on "link2" it works

Comment: I put it in a fucntion which is executed on click, maybe that was the problem? Works now :)

Comment: Yes I think it is. It works fine in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this -

```js
$(".parent-element").click(function() {
  $(".parent-element").removeClass("myClass");
  $(this).addClass("myClass");
})
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link1">link</h2>
</a>
<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link2">link</h2>
</a>
<a class="parent-element">
  <h2 class="link3">link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can target the parent with event.target.parentNode.classList.add("clicked")
but with your current code, you don't need to target the parent or use js to change the color. Because  tag is the clickable element(not h2) and when you click on it, browser knows the event, target element etc.. You can simply create a css class like

```
a.parent-element:visited {
  color: green;
}
```

so, you dont even need js for it

Comment: the effect is meant to be removed once another link is clicked. also ":visited"

Comment: oh ok then. js is required :)